# jekyll posts not displaying/formatting correctly on github pages (rest of site is OK though)

Tags: ruby, github, jekyll

I was quite happy when I finally managed to get this site online, but unfortunately the posts don't format or style correctly and I don't know what the problem is. Its located at https://github.com/skydusk/skydusk.github.io and the site is here: http://skydusk.github.io/

Can anyone tell me what i've done wrong here?

config.yml

```js
##The website title
name: skydusk
url: "http://skydusk.github.io"
##Markdown processor
markdown: kramdown
##syntax highlighter. change it to pygments
highlighter: pygments

##define base_url for valid usage in sitemap.xml and robots.txt
base_url: /skydusk
sass:
  sass_dir: _sass
  style: :compressed
paginate: 5
paginate_path: "page:num"
##The website description (to be used in meta tags)
description: just another personal blog
##Some frequently used keywords on your website
keywords: windows, storage, crashplan, synology, backups, itunes

##define this for disqus comment support
#disqus: skydusk

##set this to enable google analytics
#ga_id: UA-66844898-1
#ga_domain: www.skydusk.com

##Some commonly used links
links:
  facebook: username
  twitter: username
  email: info@skydusk.com
  github: username

##put desired image in img/ directory and set the value accordingly. If not defined, a placeholder image will be used.
about_image: placeholder.jpg
##comment this if you want full width posts with no sidebar
sidebar: off
```

Comment: what issue are you facing?

Answer (score 3):

the problem was in default.html. 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">` had to be changed to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

It was the lack of a dash at the start that was causing it, thanks to nowonmai666 over on reddit. I hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 1):

baseurl is broken somewhere and someone needs to figure it out.
`'/'` points to the root of the volume and is incorrect.
`'./'` is more correct.

Comment: Life saver! Thank you!
This answer needs some upvotes!

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a problem with your `_layout/post` file ([here](https://github.com/skydusk/skydusk.github.io/blob/master/_layouts/post.html)) and it doesn't load the CSS. Check if the CSS for posts are good or try another template.

Comment: the problem was in default.html. <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> had to be changed to <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css"> It was the lack of a dash at the start that was causing it, thanks to nowonmai666 over on reddit. I hope this can help someone.

Comment: Great! Enjoy your jeckyll

Answer (score 0):

Your original code, forked from bitwiser, was modified.

In jekyll calling an asset is usually made like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/css/main.css" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">
```

or

```
<script src="{{ site.baseurl }}/js/script.js"></script>
```

In you case :

Setting `baseurl` to nothing (`baseurl :`) and calling assets appropriatelly is ok.